# Judo experience in Tokyo (for a day or two)

Tags: tokyo, sport

I practice judo on a regular basis and will be traveling to Tokyo for a few days. I don't speak Japanese. I would like to experience the local judo atmosphere, and probably learn a few things. [Kodokan](http://kodokanjudoinstitute.org/en/learn/kodokan/formality/) has lessons geared towards foreigners, but I am not sure it fits such short periods.

Where in Tokyo can I learn judo from a local teacher for a day or two?

Comment: Did you manage to go and find out already? The way I read the link you provide in your Q, they really accept you even for a day, I mean if you pay the daily rate they also waive the membership fee. I'd defs give it a try if you fit their advanced level classes!

Answer (score 4):

Ask your teacher and other people in your dojo.

I practice Kendo, and when someone goes abroad and wants to practice there they first ask if anyone knows a teacher/dojo at the destination.
A lot of teachers trained in Japan or personally know teachers there, so it's a good bet you'll get some names.

Going through a network of practitioners is considered more polite (in most places, but especially in Japan) and will probably provide a better experience.

Comment: @pnuts I do not understand your comment. Do you mean to say it does not answer the question? If so, I believe it does, by specifying a typical source for this kind of query. If it was more common to just pop in to a dojo without getting a reference, I would have left a comment instead, but it's not, and thus the answer.

Comment: Oh, OK, sure. If I hear of a place like that I will definitely add it, and if such places are more common for Judo than for Kendo I assume someone will answer more specifically in the future. Just saw there was no answer and gave the one that I would have liked to receive 10 years ago when I had a similar question (that would have saved me some embarrassment...) :)